# Installing a UWP package on Windows 10 gives HashMismatch certificate error

Tags: windows, uwp, certificate, installation

We have previously successfully installed a packaged debug version of our application on Windows 10.

When now try to install by running the Add-AppDevPackage.ps1, when it prompts me to install the certificate, I get the error:

> Error: could not install the certificate. Status: HashMismatch. For
>   more information, see http://go.Microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=252740

I can see that the appropriate certificate in the Trusted People certificate store - so the Certificate has been installed ok.

Has anyone seen this and/or got a solution to this problem?

Comment: We've just faced with the same problem. Did you find the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the certificate is already installed, you don't need to run the powershell script. Have you tried to double click the package to install?

Comment: Unfortunately double-clicking the package give the error "Ask the developer for a new app package. In this one, the computed hash value doesn't match the hash value stored in the block map"

Comment: Appx installer validates that your package has not been modified. Maybe it's a download failure. Can you produce a new appx or ask the developer to create a new one?

Comment: I am the developer! I'm getting this error with a package I am sideloading from a USB memory stick. It previously installed fine.